# How to randomly choose columns from a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file (tab delimited)

```
Name Attribute1 Attribute2 ..........Attribute1000    
aaaa   1           100                  0    
bbbb   0            20                  50    
cccc   10           20                  30
```

I want to randomly choose 25 columns from the Attributes but always keep the first column (Name). How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Completely random, as is rolling twenty-five 999-sided dice, or uniquely random, like drawing twenty-five cards out of a 999-card deck?

Comment: I know sort -R followed by head -n 25 will give a random subset of rows. Yes, I want the random draw on column to be made only once , not for each line. I want the final text file to have a header indicating which column has been chosen

Comment: @Jack it would be 1k sided dice and a 1k card deck, there's 1001 columns

Answer (score 1):

OK -- given all the info in the comments, we get the columns like this:

```
$ columns=1,$( for (( ii=2; ii<=1000; ii++ )); do echo $ii; done | sort -R | head -25 | sort -n | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//' )
```

Then, we print out those columns like so:

```
$ cut --fields=${columns} columns.txt
```

I've just put in the headers in a one-line file:

```
$ for (( ii=1; ii<=1000; ii++ )); do
> echo -n "col${ii}<tab>" >> columns.txt
> done
```

(Note that that `<tab>` is just a placeholder I put in so you could see it.  Don't actually type `<tab>`.)

So now, when I run those commands:

```
$ columns=1,$( for (( ii=2; ii<=1000; ii++ )); do echo $ii; done | sort -R | head -25 | sort -n | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//' ) 

$ echo $columns
1,2,99,122,129,158,187,268,323,351,353,385,404,408,441,464,538,548,575,617,670,705,716,718,721,810

$ cut --fields=${columns} columns.txt 
col1    col2    col99   col122  col129  col158  col187  col268  col323  col351  col353  col385  col404  col408  col441  col464  col538  col548  col575      col617  col670  col705  col716  col718  col721  col810
```

Comment: Nice, although rather than a for loop to generate the numbers, perhaps `seq` or `jot` (neither of which is standardized) or `yes '' | nl -ba | sed -e 1d -e 1000q` (which is standard)

Comment: Whatever -- that's a style issue, so I don't care either way.

Answer (score 1):

First, craft a sequence of the columns to display : the first one followed by 25 unique random ones.

```
TOTAL_COLUMN_AMOUNT=1001
TARGET_COLUMN_AMOUNT=25

columns=(1)               # initialize an array with the columns that must always be picked
while [ ${#columns[@]} -lt $(( TARGET_COLUMN_AMOUNT + 1 )) ]; do #until we have enough data
    current_column=$(( (RANDOM % TOTAL_COLUMN_AMOUNT) + 1 ))     #pick a random index
    if [[ ! " ${columns[@]} " =~ " $current_column " ]]; then    #if it's not already there
        columns[${#columns[@]}]=$current_column                  #append it to the array
    fi
done
#echo ${columns[@]}
```

Then, you can use `awk` to display only the selected columns :

```
awk -v var="${columns[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(columns,awk_columns," ")};{for (i in awk_columns) {print $i}}'
```